# How Do I Load Angular Routes From An API without ComponentFactoryResolver?

Tags: angular

I need to load a list of available Angular routes from an API for a given user. My API response will look something like this:

```json
{
    // other data
    link: '/path',
    component: 'MyComponent'
}
```

Somehow, 'MyComponent' needs to translate to `Type<MyComponent>`, but the `ComponentFactoryResolver` and `ComponentFactory` is deprecated.

I would also like to lazy-load the component, but somehow need the file path to provide to the `import` required by `loadChildren` in the Angular `Route`.

Can anyone help?